# If key exists in nested dictionary then print value for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column called  `metadata` and a print of the column gives the following data:

```
[NaN, 
[{'raw': '"Kate Grape"', 'email': 'green@grapes.com', 'firstName': 'Kate', 'lastName': 'Grape'}],
[{'raw': '"Blue Sky"', 'email': 'white@clouds.com'}],
[{'raw': '"Cement Block"', 'email': 'concrete@cement.com', 'firstName': 'Cement', 'lastName': 'Block}],
NaN, NaN, NaN,  [{'raw': '"Sahara Desert"', 'email': 'nowater@dusty.com', 'firstName': 'Sahara', 'lastName': 'Desert'}], NaN....]
```

And so on

I'm trying to transform the column by looping over the nested dictionary to extract the first names and last names however given that all of the entries don't have `firstName` and `lastName` keys, I'm running into errors. I don't want to drop the rows without them because there are other columns in my dataframe with corresponding rows I need to keep.

I've tried:

```
def name(data):
    names=[]
    for item in range(len(df['metadata'])):
      if pd.notnull(df['metadata'][item]):
         if df['metadata'][item][0].get('firstName') is None:
            continue
         else:
            names.append(df['metadata'][item][0]['firstName']
    return names 

df['metadata'] = name(df['metadata'])
```

Along with a few different variations but I'm getting errors as `KeyError: 'firstName'` or the length not matching the index. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: sounds like you just need to add some `try:... except:...` in there for error handling. That is, `try` to do something on firstname, `except KeyError:` to do whatever it should do if that doesn't exist (just `pass` it to skip, maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

add a `try:... except:...` block in there like this. I also changed the if-check to use `is not None` instead of your true -> pass / false -> do something idiom.

```py
def name(data):
    names=[]
    for item in range(len(df['metadata'])):
      if pd.notnull(df['metadata'][item]):
        try:
            if df['metadata'][item][0].get('firstName') is not None:
                names.append(df['metadata'][item][0]['firstName']
        except KeyError:
            names.append(np.NaN)
    return names 

df['metadata'] = name(df['metadata'])
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this, and it's throwing the length error: ```Length of values (14) does not match length of index (28)``` which is confusing me since I've set the range to the length of the data. It's only returning the values that do exist whereas I'd like it to return the existing values AND fill the missing ones with NaN. Any pointers?

Comment: i've edited my post - you need to do `names.append(np.NaN)` (and also have `import numpy as np` at the beginning) when the keyerror is hit. otherwise it'll return a list with fewer elements than the dataframe has rows